# Extract values from dynamic array

Tags: regex, regex-group

**Here is the cases I need to handle while extracting string from response.**

- Need to replace a default string (no keyword) when dynamic array has
  no data. ie., [""]

  RegEx result should be: no keyword
- Need to extract data when response array has only one value ie., "[dataOne]"

  RegEx result should be: dataOne
- Need to extract first data when response array has more than one value ie.,     "[dataOne, dataTwo, dataThree]"

  RegEx result should be: dataOne

Here is my sample response:
**positive_keywords** is the array i need to extract from.

```
{
 "@odata.context":"http://xxxyyy.com","@odata.type":"#xxx.Services.Models.ContestSearchSvcMdl","advertiser_username":"yyy","company_name":"yyy","contest_mode":"TLP","is_private_invite":false,"positive_keywords":"[data one]","apply_credit_on_accept":true,"apply_credit_on_win":false,"auto_switch_target_ad":null,"id":"4276553b-988899cb-4577-800081-668ca2c05301","account_id":"0a5500cc1457-2049-4a2f-8ccc24e-055f1e935587","ad_group_id":"becccca7af6-6fc1-46cccab-877d-a15e812baa59","ad_group_name":"BRRRAND+EXACdFFT+ExpdddeDDrian","ad_group_label":null,"publisher_adgroup_id":null,"advertiser_id":"338000fa52c-e1fa-4b79-82a5-8b433615a2ef","campaign_id":"2ee1f0000f3-8d4a-4970-b009b8-3763a5f39474","campaign_name":"Brand+UKK+ENRG+RLFSA","publisher_adcampaign_id":null,"confidence":null
}
```

As now I've below regex but above conditions are not handled.

```
\"positive_keywords\":"\[([^,]*)
```

Comment: Why not parsing the JSON? I mean, convert the String to JSON, and using some programming language, extract the key you're looking for.

Comment: here is the situation where i've to achieve it via regex.

Comment: this is not going to related to any programming. I've to do some cases in Jmeter

Comment: You'll need some logic to print "no keyword". It cannot be achieved by simply using a regex. A regex can *match* patterns.

Comment: ok can you give your solution on other 2 cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\"positive_keywords\":"\[([^,\]]*)(?:,|\])
```

Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/hbOt46/2). Group 1 contains your expected result.

If the array is empty, group 1 will return an empty string. You'll have to use something else than a regex to replace this case with your `no keyword` default string.

**Explanation.** `(?:,|\])` matches either the end of the array (case for single item in array), or the beginning of the second element (case for several items in array). `?:` makes it a non-capturing group, so the match result for this group won't be stored.